# Caculate $\int_{-2}^{2}\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\ln(1+x^2)dx$

Tags: integration

> $\int_{-2}^{2}\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\ln(1+x^2)dx$

My work:
The origin $=-\int_{-2}^{2}\ln(-x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\ln(1+x^2)dx$, I think maybe we can exploit some integral properties related to odd function by playing with bounds but I don't see it.

EDIT:The origin $=-\int_{-2}^{2}\ln(-x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\ln(1+x^2)dx$ I accidently  made a mistake in my original step. It is actually $ \int_{-2}^{2} \ln( x + \sqrt{1+x^2} ) \ln( 1+x^2) dx$

Comment: $1+x^2$ is always a giver for a tangent substitution, maybe try doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=-x$, so $-du=dx$:
$$\int_{2}^{-2} -\ln{\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}-u\right)} \ln{\left(1+u^2\right)} \; du$$
Now, use the $-1$ to switch the bounds of the integral:
$$\int_{-2}^2 \ln{\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}-u\right)} \ln{\left(1+u^2\right)} \; du$$
Now, add the original integral $I$ to the integral above:
$$2I=\int_{-2}^2 \ln{\left(1+x^2\right)}\bigg[\ln{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right)}+\ln{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right)} \bigg] \; dx$$
Use log properties to get:
$$2I=\int_{-2}^2 \ln{\left(1+x^2\right)} \left(\ln{1} \right) \; dx$$
$$2I=0$$
$$\boxed{I=0}$$

Comment: Thank you! I am confused with $\int_{-2}^2 \ln{\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}-u\right)} \ln{\left(1+u^2\right)} \; du$,, if use $u=-x$ maybe will be changed into $\int_{2}^{-2} \ln{\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}-u\right)} \ln{\left(1+u^2\right)} \; du$

Comment: @red_rose I'll update my post to show a couple more steps.  You're forgetting that $du=-dx$.

Comment: I understand, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$I = \int_{-2}^{2} ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})ln(1+x^2)dx$

$ x= tan\phi$

$ dx = sec^2 \phi d\phi$

$ I= 2\int_{-2}^{2} \ln ( \tan x + \sec x)  \ln \sec (x)  \mathbb{dx}$

$ I = 2 \int_{-2}^{2} \ln (secx - tanx) \ln \sec (x) dx$

$ 2I = 2[ \int_{-2}^{2} \ln \sec(x) [ \ln(secx - tanx) + \ln(secx+tanx)]$

Now can you finish?